# Kotlin MainActivity WebView loadUrl from FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, webview

In my Kotlin app in my MainActivity I have a WebView and I want to loadUrl when on the FirebaseMessagingService the function onNewToken is called:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        val myWebView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/")
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt**

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        Log.e("log", "new token: $token")
        getSharedPreferences("_", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("fb", token).apply()
        //here I want to loadUrl
    }
}
```

how can I do that?

Comment: You could use a `LocalBroadcastManger`

Comment: @gtxtreme LocalBroadcastManger is deprecated

Comment: Use the Reactive approach then

Comment: how does it work? could you provide an example?

Comment: You can see below for an approach